# nodemon server is getting crashed after printing the name in terminal

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io, nodemon

I am building a chat website using socket.io and node.js. In live server I have given a prompt where the user is asked to enter the name in order to join the chat and I am printing the name of the user in the terminal of Visual Studio Code using console.log but, as soon as I am entering the name in prompt and pressing enter key, the name is getting printed in he terminal but after the name is printed, the NODEMON server is crashing down. I am refreshing the server over and over again. I am trying with different names but every time the same problem is occuring.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>YouChat.com</title>
    <script src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="js/client.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <img class = "logo" src="chat.png" alt="">
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="message right">Somenath: Hi Sir, How are you?</div>
        <div class="message left">Warren Buffet: I am fine. How about you?</div>
    </div>

    <div class="send">
        <form action="#" id="send-container">
            <input type="text" name="messageInp" id="messageInp">
            <button class="btn">Send</button>

        </form>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "nodeserver",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a web chat application",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Somenath Choudhury",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "socket.io": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

style.css

```
.logo{
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;

}
 
body{
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(206, 32, 212))
    

} 

.container{
    max-width: 955px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: auto;
    height: 60vh;
    padding: 33px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
}

.message{
    /* background-color: grey; */
    width: 24%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 17px 12px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
.left{
    background-color: rgb(32, 184, 32);
    float: left;
    clear: both;

}

.right{
    background-color: rgb(195, 186, 186);
    float: right;
    clear: both;

}

#send-container{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 985px;
    width: 100%;
}

#messageInp{
    width:93%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 34px;
}
.btn{
    cursor:pointer;
    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 34px;
}
```

index.js

```
const io = require('socket.io')(8000)

const users = {};

io.on('connection', socket =>{
    socket.on('new-user-joined', name =>{
        console.log("New User:-",name)
        users[socket.id] = name;
        socket.brodcast.emit('user-joined', name)
    })

    socket.on('send', message =>{
        socket.brodcast.emit('receive', {message: message, name: user[socket.id]})
    });
})
```

client.js

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:8000');

const form = document.getElementById('send-container')

const messagInput = document.getElementById('messageInp')

const messageContainer = document.querySelector(".container")

const name = prompt("enter your name to join");

socket.emit('new-user-joined', name)
```

Error in terminal when I am writing any name in prompt in browser.

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\youchat> cd .\nodeServer\
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\youchat\nodeServer> nodemon .\index.js
[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node .\index.js`
New User:- Somenath
C:\Users\user\Desktop\youchat\nodeServer\index.js:9
        socket.brodcast.emit('user-joined', name)
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\youchat\nodeServer\index.js:9:25)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Socket.onevent (C:\Users\user\Desktop\youchat\nodeServer\node_modules\socket.io\dist\socket.js:253:20)
    at Socket._onpacket (C:\Users\user\Desktop\youchat\nodeServer\node_modules\socket.io\dist\socket.js:216:22)
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\youchat\nodeServer\node_modules\socket.io\dist\client.js:205:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Problem faced in browser

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: I think this is just a small typo, you have `brodcast` where you should have`broadcast`

Comment: @JohnPavek Thanks for your help Sir. It has worked successfully.